# How to manipulate the Original Version Field value in a DataSet

Tags: .net, ado.net

How can I manipulate write the Original Values in a DataSet row?

Why I need to do this?

I need to do this because our new Version of the Database has changed its structure. However, there are still clients out there sending DataSets with the old structure. So I add the required fields on the fly, and I set their values as needed. Then, I should be able to update the Database with the DataAdapters, as usual.

In order to make the DELETE operation work, I should be able to set the original Version of a the primary key fields in the DataSet, because the DataAdapter uses the Original version to construct the parameter value for the Delete Command.

However, I haven't found any way to do this. The following code does not even compile:

```
ds.Tables["Table"].Rows[0]["NewField",  DataRowVersion.Original]=23;
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

To change in existing database table schema rename/copy table and do application changes compatible with new table and do background operation when no traffic on site update new table with original table insert data with primary key.

The original data come into changed table after doing this operation again make code live and rename changed table to original table. I hope this do work.

Comment: No, I do not intend to keep an old table on the database. I just should be to change the submitted dataset to a new structure on the fly, in-memory...

Answer (score 0):

Call DataTable.AcceptChanges() method , this makes the Current/Proposed version to Original version. hope it works for you.

**1. Updated : I was able to get that by below steps**

- Create new datatable(say dt2) with same schema as original
  datatable(say dt1) + new identity column
- Populate dt2 with original
  values from dt1, also populate new column value as desired
- Call   accept changes on dt2(new datatable)
- Now copy dt1 current values to dt2

So you have both current as well as original values including original value of new column.

I did small piece of code, can share if required but logic is simple.

Comment: Unfortunately, calling AcceptChanges means I am loosing all pending Updates. This renders the dataset useless, because the reason the client submitted it to the server was because it contains updates which should be written to the db.

Comment: Got it, do not see any method to set original values of particular column or call AcceptChanges() on column....  will try something with datarow events and add if any credible